# How to replace the top shell script?

Tags: top

Can the top command in `/usr/bin` be replaced? I read on superuser that it can hide processes if compromised. I want to delete top and get a fresh new script using `apt-get` from Ubuntu official repositories.

Comment: Refresh it do what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`top` is a part of `procps` package you can reinstall it using:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall procps
```

or install a version from a repository which you trust, run `apt-cache policy proccps`, which outputs:

```
procps:
  Installed: 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.3
  Candidate: 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.3
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.3 500
        500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

pick a version from a repository which you trust and specifically install that one:

```
sudo apt remove procps
sudo apt install procps=2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.3
```

You can also check and see if this file is compromise using `dpkg -V`:

run:

```
dpkg -V procps
```

If `top` has been compromised it will show you an output look like:

```
??5??????   /usr/bin/top
```

otherwise it show nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't we take care of probably enabled PPA's, as untrusted PPA's are a common way to compromise the system?

Comment: I updated my answer, however I strongly recommend not using PPA's or sources we don't trust in first place. IMO Once they cause the damage it's hard to discover and fix.

Comment: Looks perfect, a pity we can't upvote twice...

Comment: Thank you, I got a downvote but I couldn't find the answer (procps). Try searching for top ...